# Power Query Formula Language - Get children based on parent adjacent column value

Tags: excel, powerquery

bear with me, this is my first attempt using the Power Query Formula Language. I need some advice on how to solve a particular problem sorting and filtering source data.

*I now got this current source data, structured like this:*

[image]

*Using this power query:*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="EmployeeOrganization"]}[Content],
    ListEmployees = Table.Group(Source, {"Organization"}, {{"Employee", each Text.Combine([Employee],","), type text}}),
    CountEmployees = Table.AddColumn(ListEmployees, "Count", each List.Count(Text.Split([Employee],","))),
    SplitEmployees = Table.SplitColumn(ListEmployees, "Employee", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv),List.Max(CountEmployees[Count])),
    Transpose = Table.Transpose(SplitEmployees),
    PromoteHeaders = Table.PromoteHeaders(Transpose, [PromoteAllScalars=true])
in
    PromoteHeaders
```

*I am able to produce the following result:*

[image]

To avoid having to add the organization name to every single employee in the source, I would like the organization name to act as an parent-group, with the employees as children. I would also like the result to only fetch the organizations (+ employees) that has status Active = Yes.

*The desired source should look similar to this:*

[image]

*So that the desired result should look similar to this: (Apple is gone due to Active = NO)*

[image]

I am stuck at this point and need some advice on how can I modify my Power Query Formula to:

1. Only fetch Organizations that are **Active** (Does not matter if they have employees or not)
2. Somehow **link** the children Employees to the correct Organizations. (Without having to write the org name in every adjacent employee column)

(Excel file can be found [her](https://ufile.io/vahki2sf))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PQ, you'll need to fill in the blank rows, then Pivot with no aggregation.

See the comments in the code, and follow the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**Source**
[image]

**Custom Function**
***Rename:** fnPivotAll*

```
//credit: Cam Wallace  https://www.dingbatdata.com/2018/03/08/non-aggregate-pivot-with-multiple-rows-in-powerquery/

(Source as table,
    ColToPivot as text,
    ColForValues as text)=> 

let
     PivotColNames = List.Buffer(List.Distinct(Table.Column(Source,ColToPivot))),
     #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Source, PivotColNames, ColToPivot, ColForValues, each _),
 
    TableFromRecordOfLists = (rec as record, fieldnames as list) =>
    
    let
        PartialRecord = Record.SelectFields(rec,fieldnames),
        RecordToList = Record.ToList(PartialRecord),
        Table = Table.FromColumns(RecordToList,fieldnames)
    in
        Table,
 
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "Values", each TableFromRecordOfLists(_,PivotColNames)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",PivotColNames),
    #"Expanded Values" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Values", PivotColNames)
in
    #"Expanded Values"
```

**Basic Query**

```
let

//Read in data and set data types
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45W8k12yc9LzEkpVtJRAqLI1GKlWJ1oEDMgtSS1CCQK5XvlpyLzEvPgXMeCgpxUiH6/fJgC38SiSiT1jjmZyXAN7vn56TAdyDYmluYgaXHKTwLzYgE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Organization = _t, Employee = _t, Active = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Organization", type text}, {"Employee", type text}, {"Active", type text}}),

//replace blanks with null if not already there
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type","",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Organization", "Employee", "Active"}),

//fill down the Company and active columns    
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Replaced Value",{"Organization", "Active"}),

//Filter to show only Active="Yes and Employee not null
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each ([Employee] <> null) and ([Active] = "Yes")),

//Pivot with no aggregation
//could do this with grouping, but easier (and maybe faster, with a custom function
    pivotAll = fnPivotAll(#"Filtered Rows","Organization","Employee"),

//remove unneeded Active column and set data types
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(pivotAll,{"Active"}),
    typed = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",
        List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Columns"),each {_, Text.Type}))

in
    typed
```

**typed** *Results*
[image]

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed!